# how to save image name into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, upload

when i run the following code, the image gets moved to the desired folder but the nothing gets saved in the database. how to i save the name of the image in database. Please Help...

```
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO blog (title, image, content)
              VALUES ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[image]','$_POST[content]')");


    $target_Path = "uploaded/";
              $target_Path = $target_Path.basename( $_FILES['image']['name'] );
              move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_Path );
```

Comment: Not really, he wants to have that image there. ;)

Comment: ... Because you didn't include a value for that column?  The second to last line in your code references the image name.  Why don't you try using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is missing the image value in your query, try this:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO blog (title, image, content) 
VALUES ('$_POST[title]', '$_FILES[image][name]' ,'$_POST[content]')");
```

Comment: it worked with the file is being saved in .bin format in database. help!

Answer (score 2):

You need three items to match the three columns you're inserting data into.

```
 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO blog (title, image, content) VALUES ('$_POST[title]', '' ,'$_POST[content]')");
```

You also need to rethink your strategy of passing user inputs directly into the database without first sanitizing them.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection